# Which is better Statement or PrepareStatement

Tags: java, android

Acutually I am not Understanding how the PrepareStatement will give high performance than Statement.

Comment: I'm a C++ developer and what is this?

Comment: @chris not to mention C, .NET, and Android (to an extent).

Comment: An answer to this question can be easily found by yourself.

Answer (score 3):

From [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) :

> The main feature of a PreparedStatement object is that, unlike a
>   Statement object, it is given a SQL statement when it is created. The
>   advantage to this is that in most cases, this SQL statement is sent to
>   the DBMS right away, where it is compiled. As a result, the
>   PreparedStatement object contains not just a SQL statement, but a SQL
>   statement that has been precompiled. This means that when the
>   PreparedStatement is executed, the DBMS can just run the
>   PreparedStatement SQL statement without having to compile it first.

But the biggest reason to use a prepared statement is that you don't have to sanitize your inputs and format them as strings : all prepared statement API do that for you, in a secure and efficient way.

Comment: More to add to this, by secure it means, that SQL Injection can be prevented if using PreparedStatement.

Answer (score 1):

Statement is compiled every time you use it. PreparedStatement is pre-compiled hence you save time on its compilation in the subsequent requests. That's just the one reason.

Please check their documentation for more differences.